# Is it possible to export images from my PSD with a higher resolution?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, resolution

I made a 1920 x 8000px PSD file with lots of great pictures, logos and text.
Our programmer now need the pictures I used as single JPGs with a minimum width of 1170 px so the pictures are content aware and scale well on smartphones etc.

My problem is that I made the design for desktop and used the slice tool around every picture so I can export them easy but their size is now around 350px width. 
All of those pictures are smart objects and lead to a high resolution picture with around 4000px width.

Now my question: Is it possible to export my pictures out of my psd file with a higher resolution?

The pictures are sometimes tweaked or have a certain cutting, so just using the original file wont work. The information should be there somehow in the smart objects.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible in your case, since your smart objects are scaled down in your PSD.

An easy solution in this case would be to scale your whole PSD file up and then export the sliced smart objects. This way you don't have to mess around with rescaling smart objects individually.

Comment: Do slices scale which the document when you change size? (I have no idea)

Comment: Thats a great Idea, I will try that.

Comment: @Cai yes, that's why it's so easy